# HTTP Request in Jmeter: How can i combine 2 parameters into 1?

Tags: api, url, parameters, jmeter

I am trying to preform API load test using Jmeter and i wonder...
Can i combine 2 parameters into 1?

For example: instead of the following request:
[ip]/[address]?$[ParamA]&$[ParamB]

I would like 
[ip]/[address]?$[ParamA]+$[ParamB]

so that the passing parameter will be

ParamAParamB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the + sign in between like ${ParamA}${ParamB}.
Hope this helps.